# Flickr API request over HTTPS, is it possible?

Tags: rest, https, flickr

After migration to `https` we had a problem with the flickr-api. Cannot find whether the [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/request.rest.html) supports `rest` over `https`?

We expect to make this kind of request which works fine over `http` and no way over `https`.

```
https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&sort=interestingness-desc&method=flickr.photos.search&tags=Italy&tag_mode=all&api_key=<key>
```

Any help please or advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply replace: **http://api.flickr.com/services**
with: **https://secure.flickr.com/services**

Taken from [Here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/yws-flickr/message/7839)

**** Update ****

As Michael pointed out, the URL has changes and it's now - https://api.flickr.com/services

Comment: The URLs have since [changed](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.overview.html) and the secure address is now `https://api.flickr.com/services`

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of searching and posting at [yws-flickr](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/yws-flickr/). We've seen for two workarounds:

1. proxying flickr request through your server via https (more load and
   some security issues may come out)
2. pereodically update database of
   links via cron service (**implement this one**)